# Deploy .Net Core as DLL to IIS - Failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" site.dll'

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I have a .Net Core web application targeting net461 Framework.  It was originally producing an .EXE and working fine when deploying to IIS.  I want to change to a portable app, so I changed "buildOptions" in ProjectJson as follows:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": false,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "debugType": "portable" 
},
```

Now when I compile I get a DLL and it runs fine in IIS Express, but when I publish to IIS and change the web.config aspnetcore element to:

```
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myWebApp.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

The project fails to run and I see "Failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" MyWebApp.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'" in the application event log.

Attempting to run from command line with "dotnet mywebapp.dll" results in:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to   
execute the application was not found in 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ETimeCore2'.
```

So I found and copied hostpolicy.dll to the directory and now get:

```
Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting 
CORE HOST_TRACE environment variable to 1
```

I did set the CORE HOST_TRACE to 1 and got a verbose response of all the dlls being loaded with just that one error (above) at the end so it added no value.

Any idea what I am doing wrong??  I prefer a DLL to an EXE because to publish changes when an .EXE, you have to recycle the app pool first which is a real pain.

Comment: Did you... `CORE HOST_TRACE environment variable to 1` ?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't exactly sure where to add that, so I edited System Environment Variables and set COREHOST_TRACE (the space in post was inadvertant between "CORE" and "HOST") to 1, but I still get the same message and see no trace output.

Comment: Ok I got the trace to work and all that does is produce a verbose response of all the dlls that are being loaded followed by that same error message at very end (no other errors other then the same one above).  I edited my question to include this info.

Comment: @Brian, Where did you set `COREHOST_TRACE` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `dotnet mywebapp.dll` if disable "emitEntryPoint".

`emitEntryPoint` indicates whether the project is a console application vs. a library. From [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0-preview2/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel/CompilationOutputFiles.cs#L32-L35):

```
if (framework.IsDesktop() && compilerOptions.EmitEntryPoint.GetValueOrDefault())
{
   OutputExtension = FileNameSuffixes.DotNet.Exe;
}
```

In your case the `framework.IsDesktop()` is true, as  your target framework is `net461`, that is .NET Framework , not .NET Core. That's way you get `.exe` as output if enable `emitEntryPoint`.

---

Actually error *"The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in  "* right now means the following (see http://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2859 issue):

> dotnet.exe cannot find the entry point in mywebapp.dll

Comment: Thank you, I thought that might be the issue, so my next question is how to get VS 2015 to build as a .dll instead of an .exe.